# What kind of eye protect is appropriate for glass fibre insulation but won't fog up?

Tags: safety, tools

I've tried various goggles (some with more ventilation than others) and resorted to swimming goggles, but they all steam up after 60 seconds at the most. Maybe I sweat too much(!), but whatever I try doesn't seem to be very effective (i.e. licking the lenses, rubbing with a potato, etc.)

Comment: In the end, I did without. I was laying it only so figured I shouldn't have too much of a problem - and I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They make a [spray](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034ZN1N6) for Hockey visors that prevents them from fogging up; I have never tried it on goggles, but it should work on goggles too. It always kept my visor fog free, and I was always hot and sweaty playing hockey.  You should be able to find it at your local sporting goods store.

Actually I can't believe I have never tried this, I'm going to spray my safety glasses right now.

Comment: I got some of that spray from a sporting goods store for my biking glasses - works well.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much luck with goggles.  I just use the regular safety glasses that look like sunglasses.  Should provide enough eye protection for doing fiberglass insulation anyways.